# Understanding the uniqueness of the ring of fraction proof in D&F.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, proof-explanation

Here is the part that I do not understand in the proof of theorem 15 (on pg. 261 of Dummit & Foote, 3rd edition):

> [image]

Here is Theorem 15:

> [image]

Can someone tell me please how this shows the uniqueness of the field of fraction $Q$?

Comment: Q is only unique in the precise sense mentioned, ie, it is the smallest commutative ring containing R as a subring and D as units. Smallest in the sense that any other ring satisfying those criteria would contain an isomorphic copy of Q.

Comment: So what exactly are the authors doing in this paragraph? and why $rd^{-1} \in \operatorname{ker} \Phi$ implies $r \in  \operatorname{ker} \Phi  \cap R$? @scleaver

Comment: The authors are explicitly constructing the injective ring homomorphism that is guaranteed to exist by the uniqueness property. As for your second question, it follows from the fact that d maps to a unit.

Comment: I think the property (2) "uniqueness" is confusingly phrased as it is a universal property which by standard tricks induces uniqueness up to unique isomorphism. However, it is in my opinion significantly stronger and does not incorporate any uniqueness of the object respectively induced morphism. (I would actually throw in that $\Psi$ is a unique lift of $\varphi$)

Comment: @scleaver my understanding (I could be wrong) is that they are proving uniqueness, not using it.

Comment: @Enkidu I believe you are referring to two uniqueness, one that is used and one that is required to be proved, am I correct? if so, can you please state this uniquenesses clearly?

Comment: @scleaver for my second question, so should it be $\cap D$ not $\cap R$?

Comment: @Emptymind They prove there version of "uniqueness" which is not really uniqueness but a universal property, and there the step you copied literally is proving that the lift of an injective map stays injective, so they essentially assume that something is in the kernel and then prove that that element is zero